# Getting lat / long for returned WIFI scan in Android

Tags: android, wifi

I have been playing around with the WifiManager to do a Scan and get a list of wifi's in range. I want to be able to plot these on a map. The results that are being returned don't seem to have any kind of property that I can use for lat or long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WifiManager will not give you any kind of location data.  You must use the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).  The LocationManager will provide location data based on the user's GPS and nearby Wifi networks.

See `NETWORK_PROVIDER - This provider determines location based on availability of cell tower and WiFi access points. Results are retrieved by means of a network lookup.`

Answer (score 0):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

**This is not possible.**

There is nothing in the various 802.11 IEEE standards (aka Wi-Fi) itself that allow to do that, at any level. There's no geographical position notion in Wi-Fi.

To do that, you'd have to rely on higher-level protocols, which, not being mandated nor a widely spread standards implemented in all/most Wi-Fi AP or STA, will not be reliable enough to be really useful.

```
if TL;DR:
```

There is no half-serious reliable way to do this (yet some people pretend to do so) because the technology is not there for it in 2016.

But some people are working to change that.

```
else:
```

**LONG ANSWER:**

**Note 1:**

**Yet some application try to do that, by using heuristics such as:**

rotate 360 degrees around yourself when scanning,

- record Wi-Fi signal strength from AP, as supposed to be be related to the distance to it,
- ...and correlate that with scanning device geographical position - obtained by either by GPS, or, less precisely by surrounding nearby cellular antenna towers, which is available on on-line databases,
- ...to finely get a map of AP around the user.

Note that this is *very* heuristic and imprecise. For a start, Wi-Fi RSSI (Received Signal Strength Intensity) is far from being a reliable distance measurement. Ex: Are there walls? Furnitures? What is the surrounding radio noise?

**And, Note 2:**

**Still, the use case is there[*], so the market is there, so there are some efforts towards that.**

Right now (2016), there is a working group at the Wi-Fi Aliance (aka WFA aka wi-fi.org) about that.

http://www.wi-fi.org/beacon/rolf-de-vegt/never-lost-indoors-the-promise-of-wi-fi-location

Though, to begin with, this is based on `Wi-Fi Fine Timing Measurement (FTM) protocol`, leveraging on IEEE 1588 (`PTP`) and 802.1AS (`gPTP`), [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol) both from 802.1 (aka wired Ethernet). And this FTM is not there yet.

The goal of this, for now, is just to measure the *distance* of nodes. The primary motivation for this is *not* geographic position, but rather have an accurate measure of propagation delay, which is important for video/audio streaming: devices need a common wall clock to be able to play in sync, and this common clock cannot be shared if you do not know how long it takes to propagate it from node to node in the first place.

This `Wi-Fi Fine Timing Measurement` work group started in 2014. Going from that to a published completed IEEE standards, with silicon vendors support, to firmware/OS support, to an application on a device near you (and certification programs on top of that to be sure that everyone plays well with anyone), well, you'll have to wait for a couple of years. And this is just the very basic: accurately measure *distances* - nothing geographic.

So to go to "the promise of Wi-Fi location" to quote the WFA (Wi-Fi Aliance), add another couple of years. For off the shelves widely available support, may very well realistically be post 2020 IMHO.

**[*]:**

And BTW, the long-term vision uses cases and market go far beyond smartphones. It's IOT. And not "wearable IOT" or other consumer electronics gizmos fashion of the moment. Think industrial networks of wireless sensors to monitor plants/infrastructures/buildings. Consumer electronics is just the early adopters, tip of the iceberg thing.